Is it a past participle in passive voice?
There's situation like this:
A guy saw another guy being beaten by a group of men in an alley and said:
"Stop it. It's not much of a fight when you have someone outnumbered"
Am I right if I assume that "outnumbered" is a past participle in passive voice here?
So, I think I can rephrase it like:
"It's not much of a fight when there's someone outnumbered by you". Is that so?

With by possible (someone is outnumbered by you)  as is the more likely "when you outnumber someone".

"Outnumbered" is a past participle verb. Active/passive voice is best thought of as a property of clauses. In the construction at issue it is reasonable to say that there is a clause consisting just of the word "outnumbered". (It is a kind of nonfinite clause with no subject, sometimes called a bare passive.)
You can tell that the clause is in passive voice because it could be rephrased as "someone is outnumbered by enemies", which is a typical illustration of the passive construction.
